# how to create an animation using images?

Tags: animation

I have a handfull of images that I want to put into a simple program that shows me what the animation will look like?

I know photoshop could do it, but I am looking for something simple.  All I want to do is add images to the program and it just shows me what it looks like in sequence.  I had a look at some tools, but they all seem soo complicated.  Has anyone got any programs they can recommend?

Thanks

Comment: Powerpoint can be very simple to use and easy to learn program :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool Simplest Solution! which i have used many times

**PowerPoint**

> 1. Open the powerpoint presentation.
> 2. Select "File"->"Save As" (File being the large round office button)
> 3. Either click on "Save As" or click on "Other Formats"
> 4. Select where to save (this will save as a folder of images)
> 5. Under "Save type as", select "GIF" and click Save
> 6. A prompt will appear, select "Every Slide"
> 7. A prompt will tell you that it has been saved.

**GIMP**

> 1. Open GIMP
> 2. Select "File"->"Open As Layers"
> 3. Navigate to the folder of images which you created above.
> 4. Select the slides you want to open. Hold down "Ctrl" and click to select several files, or click on a file and then hold "shift" and
>      click on one further below to select those in between.
> 5. Select "Open"...Gimp will now load the images.
> 6. Select "File"->"Save As"
> 7. For the "Name", make sure it ends in ".gif" such as "example.gif" and click save
> 8. An Export File Dialog will pop up:

[image]

> 9 Another dialog will pop up:

[image]

> 10 Hit Save and you're done.

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:PowerPoint_to_animated_gif)